# How do I insert a simple value to a BLOB field using the INSERT INTO statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm making a table with 5 sample entries, but it has a BLOB datatype which is NOT NULL. How do I insert a simple value to it?

for example given the table *A* with the fields (name - VARCHAR(45), file - BLOB):

```
name | file
```

What do I put in the argument for file when I use

```
insert into A(name, file) values('abcvdfdfas', /* what do i put here */);
```

Comment: In what context? Are you trying to do this with code, or a MySQL client, and if the latter, what client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`BINARY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#operator_binary) operator:

```
INSERT INTO A(name, file) VALUES('abcvdfdfas', BINARY 'whatever');
```